# How can I declare a function or variable in a file and use it always in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I am working on a project and I have to use an alert message almost in every view controller. Particularly this one:

```
func showMessage(myMessage: String) {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "ALERT", message: myMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Using the same code over an over again makes my code verbose. This scenario goes with some other functions and some variables also. How can I declare this function somewhere in a different file and use it whenever necessary? Shall I use a singleton pattern like:

```
static let sharedInstance = viewController()
```

If so, please show me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using an extension such as:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showMessage(myMessage: String) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "ALERT", message: myMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This way you can use it in any class subclassed from UIViewController.  You could also just drop the function into a swift file as a "global function" but that's not very clean.

Comment: thank you so much, I was overlooking extension like a fool.

Comment: @ArafinRussell you're welcome!  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Your function showMessage(myMessage:) is common to all your ViewControllers. So you can either :

- Use a super class ViewController and implement your function in there :

  ```
  class BaseViewController {
      func showMessage(myMessage: String) { ... }
  }
  ```
- Use swift protocols :

  ```
  protocol MessageHelper {}

  extension MessageHelper where Self: UIViewController {
      func showMessage(myMessage: String) { ... }
  }

  extension MyViewController: MessageHelper {}
  ```

Using a shared instance that handles all your message could be another way to go.

```
class MessageController {
    static let shared = MessageController()
    private init() {}

    func showMessage(myMessage: String, viewController: UIViewController) { ... }

}
```

And just call `MessageController.shared.showMessage(myMessage:viewController:)` when you need to display a message.

Using a message controller will give you more possibilities, you can either count the number of messages displayed or filter messages to display in the same and one place.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom class for the view controllers in your app. Instead of subclassing `UIViewController`, each of your view controllers would subclass your `CustomViewController` class. Here's an example:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
    func showMessage(myMessage: String) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "ALERT", message: myMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Each view controller you create that subclasses `CustomViewController` would then have access to the `showMessage` function.